# how to retrieve appendTo() in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I appended a cloned element $canvas in DOM to the body using this code

```
 $('.' + $canvas).clone().appendTo('body');
```

but I need to retrieve it to use it like this

```
 $('ul,.map').mousemove(function (e) {
          $('.' + $canvas).offset({
              left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY
     })
 });
```

How do I retrieve a clone $canvas in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('body').last('.'+$canvas)
```

However, you're going to run into issues the second time you do your clone, since it will return two elements

Answer (score 0):

appendTo returns the appended element

```
var canvas = $('.' + $canvas).clone().appendTo('body');
```

`canvas` now contains the appended cloned element